# PHP Mysql update set replace exact match

Tags: php, mysql, replace, preg-replace, match

I need help replacing exact numbers in my database.

My table look likes this..

```
ID NAME    IMAGES
-------------------------------
1  person1  1,2,3...101,102,103
```

When I use

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET images = REPLACE(images, '3,', '') WHERE id = '1'");
```

It removes all the 3 from all numbers that end with 3..

```
13, = 1
23, = 2
113, = 11
```

Comment: You should not use a comma separated list in one of your fields. Normalize your database and store the images / image ID's in a separate table.

Comment: You should normalize your data. Much easier to work with that way.

Comment: Add a comma before the 3?

mysql_query("UPDATE table SET images = REPLACE(images, ',3,', '') WHERE id = '1'");

Btw, previups comments are ok, you should normalize your data.

Comment: What do you want to happen? You tell us what is happening but not what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned already, the correct solution is to normalize the data. However if you are *stuck with* this table structure, you can still perform a single `UPDATE` statement using 3 `CASE` conditions to match the number at the beginning, middle, or end.

To remove it from the beginning or end of the list, you may use a `SUBSTR()`, and continue using `REPLACE()` to remove it from the middle of the list.

```
UPDATE
  table
SET images = 
  CASE
    /* if 3 is in the leftmost position in the list, remove first 2 chars... */
    WHEN LEFT(images, 2) = '3,' THEN SUBSTR(images, 3)
    /* if 3 is in the rightmost position in the list, remove last 2 chars... */
    WHEN RIGHT(images, 2) = ',3' THEN SUBSTR(images, 1, LENGTH(images) - 2)
    /* Otherwise replace a single 3 bounded by commas with a single comma */
    ELSE REPLACE(images, ',3,', ',')
  END
WHERE id = '1'
```